# Understanding the implementation of DenseNet

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, torch

I am new to Python and pyTorch.
The DenseNet architecture (https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993 ) is shown in the figure. In this architecture, the features at layer i can be given as a function of the features from all the previous layers as given below.

```
 x(i)= H( [x(1), ..., x(i-1)] )
```

where [.] is the concatenation operator.

[image]

The implementation of DenseNet is given in: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/densenet.py

I am struggling to understand this implementation, particularly where the features from different layers are concatenated.

```
   new_features = super(_DenseLayer, self).forward(x)
```